# Method involving a conditional loop is unexpectedly returning nil for some values

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve a Ruby [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/is-a-number-prime/train/ruby). The aim is to write a method that returns true if a random integer (including negative integers and 0) inputted as an argument is prime, and false if it is not. My method returns the right results, when it returns results.

I've tested the method for the numbers 1-20. It returned:

- true for all 7 primes under 20 except 3, which was nil
- false for 1, 9 and 15
- nil for everything else

I also tested 43 (true) and 100 and 80 (nil). I also noticed that if I commented out the lines with return, the method returned nil for all arguments between 1 and 20.

Here's the method:

```
def isPrime(num)
  num_absolute = num.abs
  increasing_divisor = 2
  almost_num_absolute = num_absolute - 1

  if num_absolute <=1
    return false
  elsif num_absolute == 2
    return true
  else
    until num_absolute % increasing_divisor == 0 || almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor
      increasing_divisor += 1
      if num_absolute % increasing_divisor == 0
        return false
      elsif almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor
        return true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Presumably avoiding the use of Ruby's [Prime](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Prime.html) module?

Comment: If you can use [Prime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) methods it's just: `require 'prime'; Prime.prime?(n)`, where `n` is the randomly-selected integer (possibly non-positive).

Comment: Hint: Prime numbers are not divisible by any number from 2 to the square root of the number itself. There's a "math" library in Ruby, which has `Math.sqrt(number)` to get the square root of a number.

Comment: Negative numbers are not prime (and not natural numbers).

Comment: @Surya `Integer.sqrt(number)` was introduced in Ruby 2.5. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-c-sqrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the body of this `until` loop is not always run:

```
until num_absolute % increasing_divisor == 0 || almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor
```

Let's say that I pass a input of `3`. This is a prime, so this loop will run *until* `almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor`. At which point the `until` block will finish, and since your fuction doesn't specify any return value *after* the `until` block, it will just return nil (which is the 'default' return value for functions).

Now let's say you pass an input of `6`. The value of `increasing_divisor` is 2 (the starting value). 6 is divisible by 2. So, because `num_absolute % increasing_divisor == 0` is true, the body of the `until` block will never run. Again, no return value is specified after the `until` block, so the default return value (nil) is used.

A quick fix would be to add this line at the way end of the function (right before the final `end`):

```
almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor
```

Since both primes and non-primes can reach this point in the code, you want to do a final check here. If `almost_num_absolute == increasing_divisor` is true, then you know there were no divisors found, and therefore the result *is* a prime

Comment: OK, I ended the loop after the line increasing_divisor += 1 and began a new conditional based on the results of that loop. The method now provides the right results

Comment: @IvoEvansStorrie ok. Feel free to accept the answer if the problem is solved.